# Cannot run program "su ": error=13, Permission denied in Android Application

Tags: android, wifi-direct

My DHCP method returning flase. Getting error from val process: Process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands)" this line

//DHCP setup function>>

```
suspend fun dhcpSetup(): Boolean {
    var success = true
    success = success && runRootCommand("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
    success = success && runRootCommand("iptables -F")
    success = success && runRootCommand("iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -j MASQUERADE")
    success = success && runRootCommand("iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT")
    success = success && runRootCommand("iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8:53")
    success = success && runRootCommand("iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT")
    return success
}
```

//Command Execution Function>>>

```
private suspend fun runRootCommand(command: String): Boolean {
    val commands = arrayOf("su", "-c", command)
    val start: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val process: Process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands)
    val result = process.waitFor()
    val end: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("RootManager", "Command ${Arrays.toString(commands)} executed in ${end - start} ms " +
            " with result $result")
    return result == 0
}
```

Comment: do you have rooted device?

Comment: No, my device is not rooted

Answer (score 1):

`su` means Super User, these commands works only on rooted units with higher privileges and some extended APIs access. no root = no `su` execution possibility (in most cases there is no `su` executor on device at all)

btw. even your method name have "root" in its name... `runRootCommand`

Comment: In that case what would be the commands in dhcp method...?? Please let me know...!! Thanks

Comment: this is different question, I advise you to create new topic with properly formatted question, all your needs and tried ways. personally I don't have much DHCP-related knowledge in context of Android, but I doubt that you can achieve what you want without root... I suspect that one and only way may be a bit ugly workaround with creating own fake-VPN app, which in fact would bye manipulating routing, but this is only a guess...